# Looking for a way to convert SVG/Points to text (not OCR)

Tags: svg, vector, vector-graphics, points, text-recognition

I have recently been playing around with a web app that allows the user to draw paths on an SVG using touch or a stylus (the idea is to make a simple note taking web app).

Now I would like to add the ability to convert SVG Paths to text. So my question is: How do I convert the coordinates of the SVG Path to text?

I'm just at a loss of how you would call such a process (and hours of googling something with no idea what to call it has not yielded results). And when I search for something remotely linked to text recognition I can only find things about OCR.

I'm not looking for OCR, because that requires bitmap images. I'm looking for a way to convert SVG Paths or points/vectors to text.

Can anybody point me in the right direction of what this is called so I can read more about the topic and dont need to re-invent the wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: convert the SVG drawing to canvas, then it's a bitmap and you can do OCR on it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid... I was hoping to benefit from the fact that the handwriting is already in vector form, since that is the first step most OCR perform.